# How to apply grease line art across the arched shape (wrong edges)

Tags: materials, modifiers, grease-pencil, bevel, lineart

I shaped one side of the cube to make it look like a curved glass display case. My goal was to outline it with a black line, but I'm having trouble because I see black lines on other edges as well. I'm unsure how to add a black outline only around the external edges of the glass.

I've watched various tutorials on using Grease Pencil for line art, but I encounter issues when I change the line art settings (object/collection/scene).

I'm wondering if the problem is with the model itself or the modifiers I've applied (mirror/remesh/decimate). What's the best approach to achieve this effect?

[image: grease]

Attached file here:
[image]